# Calculating nCr mod p efficiently when n is very large

Tags: python, binomial-coefficients

I need to calculate `nCr mod p` efficiently. Right now, I have written this piece of code, but it exceeds the time limit. Please suggest a more optimal solution.

For my case, `p = 10^9 + 7 and 1 ≤ n ≤ 100000000`

I have to also make sure that there is no overflow as `nCr mod p` is guaranteed to fit in 32 bit integer, however `n!` may exceed the limit.

```
def nCr(n,k):
    r = min(n-k,k)
    k = max(n-k,k)
    res = 1
    mod = 10**9 + 7

    for i in range(k+1,n+1):
        res = res * i
        if res > mod:
            res = res % mod

    res = res % mod
    for i in range(1,r+1):
        res = res/i
    return res
```

PS : Also I think my code may not be completely correct. However, it seems to work for small `n` correctly. If its wrong, please point it out !

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.2

Comment: Why are you worrying about overflow? Python's integer types don't have a fixed storage space; it will take as much storage space as it needs.

Comment: @RamchandraApte: while that is true, it /is/ possible to cause an int overflow in python

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Well, the only way I know in Python 3 is to use certain C functions, such as those in the math module. Not sure about Python 2.

Comment: Also, it exceeds the time limit. Can I optimize it further ?

Comment: @RamchandraApte: you’re right. `math.e(BIG_NUMBER)` will cause an overflow. Haven’t seen it happen “naturally”, though

Comment: How quickly do you need it to work?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: this is a float ("double").  This overflows, but the integers don't.

Answer (score 12):

From http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/SRM+467 :

```
long modPow(long a, long x, long p) {
    //calculates a^x mod p in logarithmic time.
    long res = 1;
    while(x > 0) {
        if( x % 2 != 0) {
            res = (res * a) % p;
        }
        a = (a * a) % p;
        x /= 2;
    }
    return res;
}

long modInverse(long a, long p) {
    //calculates the modular multiplicative of a mod m.
    //(assuming p is prime).
    return modPow(a, p-2, p);
}
long modBinomial(long n, long k, long p) {
// calculates C(n,k) mod p (assuming p is prime).

    long numerator = 1; // n * (n-1) * ... * (n-k+1)
    for (int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        numerator = (numerator * (n-i) ) % p;
    }

    long denominator = 1; // k!
    for (int i=1; i<=k; i++) {
        denominator = (denominator * i) % p;
    }

    // numerator / denominator mod p.
    return ( numerator* modInverse(denominator,p) ) % p;
}
```

Notice that we use modpow(a, p-2, p) to compute the mod inverse. This is in accordance to Fermat's Little Theorem which states that (a^(p-1) is congruent to 1 modulo p) where p is prime. It thus implies that (a^(p-2) is congruent to a^(-1) modulo p).

C++ to Python conversion should be easy :)

Comment: Also, note that modPow is already available in the form of `pow()` in Python.

Comment: Helped me out a ton. Was hard to find this implementation elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

About the last question: I think that the mistake in your code is to compute the product, reduce it modulo `k`, and then divide the result by `r!`.  This is not the same as dividing before reducing modulo `k`.  For example, `3*4 / 2 (mod 10) != 3*4 (mod 10) / 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from sympy 1.13 (still unreleased as of today) this can be done using the function binomial_mod. This is the merged PR: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/24891

It uses a generalised Lucas theorem.